# Zendesk app POST method return status code 200 but body return null

Tags: javascript, api, http, browser, zendesk-app

1. When i use the request method on my endpoint it return me a code
   status 200 but my body is empty. Someone can help me ?

   ```
   $(function() {
     var client = ZAFClient.init();
     client.invoke('resize', { width: '100%', height: '500px' });

     client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
       function(data) {
         var userId = data['ticket.requester.id'];
         requestUserInfo(client, userId);
       }
     );

   });

       function requestUserInfo(client) {
         var settings = {
           url: `${url}`,
           type:'POST',
           headers : {
             "Content-Type": "application/json",
             "authorizationToken": "allow",
           },
           body : JSON.stringify({
             user_id: `${user_id}`
           }),
         };



         client.request(settings).then(
           function(data) {
             console.log(data)
           },
           function(response) {
             showError(response);
           }
         );
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you aren't seeing the expected results is because within your function `requesterUserInfo` method, you'll want to ensure you are passing in the ID as well and making sure to set the type to GET instead of a POST. The `client.request(settings)` method should have a `.then` that would display the data. I would kindly recommend reviewing the article shown from Zendesk:

https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001074828